# Prove all zeros of a polynomial lie in $\{|z| > 1 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to solve following problem. I tried to solve it with "Cauchy integral formula" but I couldn't. How can I solve this?!

Suppose $p_0 > p_1 > p_2 > ... >p_n > 0$. Prove that all zeros of the polynomial $p(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n p_j z^j $ lie in the $\{|z| > 1\}$.

It's problem 1.1 in  "A Course in Complex Analysis and Riemann Surfaces(Wilhelm Schlag)".

Comment: @DietrichBurde They are different. In my problem I want to show all zeros of a polynomial lie in |z| > 1, but in the other is |z| < 1. I think that solution don't work for my problem.

Comment: The text says "*doesn't lie* in the unit circle", see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980824/show-that-a-complex-polynomial-of-degree-n-doesnt-have-zeros-in-a-unit-ball?noredirect=1&lq=1). So this is a duplicate.

Comment: This question is asking how to prove that all zeros are *not* in the unit disc, so it is not a duplicate of the question asking how to prove that all zeros *are* in the unit disc.